# need to compare two table columns if no matching rows then validation error should be displayed in another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, procedural-programming

I have two tables p1 and p2  with below columns..

p1:

```
p_id        P_revid      item_type          status       rev_name       
-----     -------------  ----------------  ----------    --------------       
123         A             Part              Production    r1                      
123         B             NonPart           Released      r2    
234         A             Part              Production    r4    
567         A             Part              Snapshot      r5
```

P2:

```
id         revid          item_type         status       rev_name            
-----     -------------  ----------------  ----------    --------------       
123        B               Part           Released          r1                   
123        C               Part           Production        r12                 
234        A               Part           Production        r3    
345        A               Part           Production        r5    
567        A               Part           Production        r5
```

Below are the validations:-

here p_id+p_revid in p1 should be compared with id+revid in p2.

1. if we didn't find any record, put `id=p_id`  and `revid=p_revid` in
   `output_result` table and validaton_errror as **"Not found in target"**
2. if we find records, compare these columns and put error as eg:-
   **"Wrong_item_type"** , **"Wrong_release_status"**. as shown in
   output_result table.
3. if we found any `revid` in p2, not in as  `id` in p1 , then store id,
   revid from output_result with `validation_eror`=**"Not found in source"**

output_result:-

```
id            revid           Validation_error    
-----     -------------       ------------------------    
123        A                  Not found in target    
123        B                  Wrong_item_type, wrong_rev_name    
123        C                  Not_in_source    
567        A                  Wrong_release_status.
```

Comment: Check out the MERGE operation in TSQL; you can do 3 different operations in one statement, based on a join (plus optional conditions).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT p1.p_id, p1.p_revid,
       STUFF(
         CASE 
          WHEN p2.id IS NULL THEN ',Not found in target'
          ELSE IIF(p1.item_type <> p2.item_type, ',Wrong_item_type', '')
               +
               IIF(p1.status <> p2.status, ',Wrong_release_status', '')
               +
               IIF(p1.rev_name <> p2.rev_name, ',Wrong_rev_name', '')
         END
         ,1, 1, '') AS Validation_error
FROM p1
LEFT JOIN P2 
   ON p1.p_id = p2.id AND p1.p_revid = p2.revid

UNION ALL

SELECT p2.id, p2.revid, 'Not_in_source'
FROM p2
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM p1
    WHERE p1.p_revid = p2.revid
)
```

**Output:**

```
p_id  p_revid   Validation_error
------------------------------------------------
123   A         Not found in target
123   B         Wrong_item_type,Wrong_rev_name
234   A         Wrong_rev_name
567   A         Wrong_release_status
123   C         Not_in_source
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a2630e/4)

Comment: This works really great for me, althouhg after UNIAN ALL I had to add an empty string like this, <'' AS Validation_error> in order to work. I was trying to find example like this for long time. I am in database warehouse and involves a lot of the testing between source and target. Thank you for this @ Giorgos Betsos.